# How do I get the table column data from one model into the view of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want the customer name to appear in the customer name column on one of my model view pages, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here are my associations:

Customer Model is -

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :customer
  has_many :birds, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :customer
end
```

Bird Model is -

```
class Bird < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :appointment
end
```

I've also added this to the Bird model index view -

```
<tbody>
<% @birds.each do |bird| %>
  <tr data-link="<%= bird_path(bird) %>">
            <td><%= bird.customer_id %></td>
            <td><%= bird.name %></td>
            <td><%= bird.breed %></td>
            <td><%= bird.color %></td>
            <td><%= bird.age %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The customer parameter I'd like to pass into the customer name column on the birds index view page is customer.name, or :name. If I try that, I get an undefined methods error on my /birds page.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `bird.customer.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that this should work:

```
<%= bird.customer.name %>
```

Or - if you have birds without an customer - you might want avoid exceptions like this:

```
<%= bird.customer.try(:name) %>
```

Or - less error prone - add the following to your bird model:

```
delegate :name, to: :customer, allow_nil: true, prefix: true
```

And use it in your views like this:

```
<%= bird.customer_name %>
```

Comment: `delegate :name, to: :customer, allow_nil: true, prefix: true` would be kind of annoying if expect Polly The Parrot and get the customers name instead.

Comment: @max: Note the `prefix: true`. This delegation will not override an existing `name` method, but instead add a `customer_name` method that points to `customer.name`. You might want to read about [`delegate and the prefix option`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#method-delegation) in the Rails Guide.

Comment: Maybe the question I should have asked is: how do I put the customer name on the form for new bird, so that it gives a list of all customers to choose from? Then once I've picked the name and created the bird, how do I make that name appear under the customer name column?

Comment: @LadyStensberg: Have a look at [`collection_select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects) in the Rails Guide. You will have to add something like `<%= collection_select(:customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name) %>` to your bird creation form.

Comment: @spickermann I have, but not as you have it listed. I'll try your specific suggestion and let you know!

Comment: @spickermann I've added this to my bird _form.html.erb:   <%= f.label :Customer_selection %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name) %> It works in terms of giving me the selection, but I can't get it to show up on the birds index page :(

Comment: @LadyStensberg: Please check if `:customer_id` is in the list of permitted parameters in your `birds_controller.rb`. If not, add it. It should look like: `params.require(:bird).permit(:customer_id, :name, :breed, :color, :age)`. You must all attributes to that list, that should be updateable. Read about [permitting params in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Comment: @spickermann OMG THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THAT WORKED!!! :) I won't make that mistake again. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in your view like this :

```
<%= bird.customer.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, for the bird index page:
when you query for `Bird.all`, do `Bird.all.includes(:customer)`
then you will have access to `<%= bird.customer.name %>` in the view